# Thread synchronization to print sequential out put from multiple threads in c program

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization

Write a c program to implement two threads, one should print characters from Arr1[] in loop

```
and other
 should print numbers from Arr2[] in loop?
Input :
 char Arr1[6] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
 int Arr2[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
Output :
 a1b2c3d4e5f6
 a1b2c3d4e5f6
 a1b2c3d4e5f6
 a1b2c3d4e5f6....
```

How to do synchronization in above program to print the desire output?

I tried with thread synchronization techniques like mutex I have used but it is not displaying as per the output requirement

Please help me to find the solution

I am getting similar questions on internet but those are implemented in java or c++ I want it to be implemented in c

Comment: There is no program. Please provide an actual [mcve].

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: ["3. Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having solving it.**"](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Please [edit] the question to improve it. Please, also read this [Open letter to students with homework problems](//meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use 2 mutexes? So, first can write if they are like 1 0 and other 0 1. Each just switches both mutexes-enables others' thread, and disables its'.